# "Get" function doesn't work because not all hyphens should be replaced

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, get, str-replace

I use a Get function to look for the field `model` in an url but I have a problem when the model contains a space and a hyphen.
Example: my model in the url is "**this-f-example**" and the model in the database is "**this f-example**" (so without the first hyphen).

I wrote the following php code, but it's not sufficient. It would only look for `this f example` or `this-f-example` in my database so it would return nothing because those models don't exist.

What should I change to my code so it would look for the models `this-f example` and `this f-example` too?

Complete url: `http//:www.example.com/test.php?model=this-f-example`

Corresponding model in database: `this f-example`

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host.....');    
    $model1 = str_replace ('-', ' ', $_GET['model']);
    $model2 = $_GET['model'];

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT brand, model FROM `exampletable` WHERE model = :model1 OR model = :model2";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":model1", $model1);
    $stmt->bindParam(":model2", $model2);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      echo $result['brand']; 
      echo $result['model'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesForUsingHyphensAndDashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)**.

```
// turn 'this-f-model' to 'this[- ]f[- ]example'
$model = str_replace ('-', '[- ]', $_GET['model']);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT brand, model FROM `exampletable` WHERE model REGEXP :model";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":model", $model);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

If the variable `model` that you're sending in url must be `this-f-example`, you could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of `str_replace` to get your `model1` and `model2` for the model in the url.

Try with this code :

```
$modelUrl= $_GET['model'];    
$model1 = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $modelUrl, 1);//remove the first hyphen

$occ = preg_match_all('/-/', $modelUrl, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if ($occ !== false && $occ > 1) {
    //remove the second hyphen
   $model2 = substr_replace($modelUrl, ' ', $matches[0][2][1], strlen('-'));
}

$params = array(":model1"=> $model1,
                ":model2"=> $model2);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT brand, model FROM `exampletable` WHERE model=:model1 OR model=:model2";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

But if your problem is just the spaces in your variabale, I think a better solution is to use the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php) function which will encode the space in your varibale with `+` :

```
echo urlencode('this f-example'); // output : this+f-example
```

And when you get it with `$GET['model']`, just use the [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function to decode the varibale and remove the `+` :

```
echo urldecode($GET['model']); // output : this f-example
```

Comment: I decided to use the solution from user xdazz because it's the exact thing I was looking for and a bit easier to implement. Thanks for the effort though!