# "Get" function not all hyphens should be replaced AND ignore Umlaut

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, get, str-replace

I currently use the following `str_replace` function (as a result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656406/get-function-doesnt-work-because-not-all-hyphens-should-be-replaced)).

```
// turn 'this-f-model' to 'this[- ]f[- ]example'
$model = str_replace ('-', '[- ]', $_GET['model']);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT brand, model FROM `exampletable` WHERE model REGEXP :model";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":model", $model);
$stmt->execute();
```

I thought this would be sufficient, but now I have a new problem with a model that contains an Umlaut.

**Example:**

Model in database: this f-ëxample

I should find this model by using the following url: http//:www.example.com/test.php?model=this-f-example

With the current `str_replace` function, it doesn't find this new model. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: str_replace isn't unicode aware, and you're probably corrupting your string. done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($model)` to see what came out of the str_replace?

Comment: I'm sorry for the (very) late answer. The result is ´this[- ]f[- ]ëxample´.